# Make image as canvas background and save it with user's drawing

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, paint

I'm using the code below. My app was able to draw on the canvas and save it.

But what I want to do is make an image as the background of the canvas so when I save it, it will look like an image with the user's drawing on top of it.

Thank you so much for any help! :)

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas = null;
    while (_run){
        if(isDrawing == true){
            try{
                canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                if(mBitmap == null){
                    mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                }
                final Canvas c = new Canvas (mBitmap);

                c.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                canvas.drawColor(0xffffffff);

                commandManager.executeAll(c,previewDoneHandler);
                previewPath.draw(c);

                canvas.drawBitmap (mBitmap, 0,  0,null);
            } finally {
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to combine two images..?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Lalit Poptani, yes, something like that.

Comment: Well replying to what I know is always my pleasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this stuff,

This will return a `Bitmap` that will be a `Merged` one of `two Bitmap Images`, also it will save in the `SDCard`.

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) {

        Bitmap cs = null;
        int width, height = 0;

        if (c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) {
            width = c.getWidth();
            height = c.getHeight();
        } else {
            width = s.getWidth() + s.getWidth();
            height = c.getHeight();
        }

        cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);

        comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0, 0, null);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(s, 100, 300, null);

        /******
         * 
         *   Write file to SDCard
         * 
         * ****/

        String tmpImg = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png";
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/"+tmpImg);
            cs.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("combineImages", "problem combining images", e);
        }
        return cs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For any view that you are creating, you can create a bitmap of what it is currently displaying.
use:

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap=view.getDrawingCache();
```

Does this help you in achieving what you want ?
*be sure to recycle these bitmaps when you are done.

```
bitmap.recycle();
```

Comment: It's not saving the background image. Just the drawing.

Comment: i dont know, try this same thing with the root view or the decor view. I have used similar thing  to get images from a 3d object rendered on surface view.